# yacc do not printing AST

Tags: yacc

edit my question. 
in expression rule: **exp** does not reduced to **expression** 
for example:  **identifier**(exp)-**identifier**(exp)

run test:  http://www.interload.co.il/upload/2528784.png
in the image you can see that yacc is waiting for more input for some reason.
what is wrong with expression rule?
-----------------------------yacc code-------------------------------

```
          %{
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <string.h>
            typedef struct node
            {
                    char* token;
                    struct node* left;
                    struct node* right;
            }node;
            node* mknode(char* token,node* left, node* right);
            void printtree(node* tree);
            #define YYSTYPE struct node*
    %}
    %start s
    %token WHILELOOP
    %token STATIF
    %token ELSE
    %token MAIN
    %token POINTERERR
    %token COMMENT
    %token POINTER
    %token GREATEREQUAL
    %token LESSEREQUAL
    %token DBLAND
    %token GREATER
    %token LESSER
    %token LESSER
    %token POWER
    %token MULTIPLY
    %token MINUS
    %token PLUS
    %token AND
    %token OR
    %token NOT
    %token NOTEQUAL
    %token CHARERROR
    %token STRINGERROR
    %token POINTER
    %token INTEGER
    %token BOOLEAN
    %token DEVIDE
    %token ASSIGN
    %token EQUAL
    %token TYPE
    %token IDENTIFIER
    %token HEX IF
    %token LITERCHAR
    %token OCTAL
    %token BINARYINT
    %token LTRLSTRING
    %token COMMA COLON SEMICOLON VAR RETURN RPARENC LPARENC
    %left COMMA LPAREN RPAREN
    %left PLUS
    %left MINUS DEVIDE
    %left MULTIPLY EQUAL NOTEQUAL OR AND LESSEREQUAL GREATEREQUAL GREATER LESSER
    %right IDENTIFIER
    %%
    s: expression|operator|var_declare|if_stnt;
    {
            printf("blaAA bla/n");
    };
    expression: exp {printtree($1);}
    exp: exp PLUS exp {$$=mknode("+",$1,$3);}
                    |exp MINUS exp {$$=mknode("-",$1,$3);}
                    |exp DEVIDE exp {$$=mknode("/",$1,$3);}
                    |exp MULTIPLY exp {$$=mknode("*",$1,$3);}
                   | MINUS exp {$$=mknode("-",NULL,$2);}
                    |IDENTIFIER {$$= mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL);}

    operator: op{printtree($1);}
              op: exp EQUAL exp {$$=mknode("=",$1,$3);}
                    |exp NOTEQUAL exp {$$=mknode("!=",$1,$3);}
                    |exp OR exp {$$=mknode("||",$1,$3);}
                    |exp AND exp {$$=mknode("&&",$1,$3);}
                    |exp GREATER exp {$$=mknode(">",$1,$3);}
                    |exp GREATEREQUAL exp {$$=mknode(">=",$1,$3);}
                    |exp LESSER exp {$$=mknode("<",$1,$3);}
                    |exp LESSEREQUAL exp {$$=mknode("<=",$1,$3);}

var_declare: var {printtree($1);}
             var: VAR ident_list COLON TYPE SEMICOLON{$$=mknode("var",$2,$4);}



    ident_list: ident_list COMMA ident_list {$$=mknode(",", $1, $3);}
              |IDENTIFIER {$$= mknode(yytext,NULL,NULL);}

    if_stnt:IF LPAREN exp RPAREN
    %%
    #include "lex.yy.c"
    main()
    {
            return yyparse();
    }
    node* mknode(char* token,node*left,node* right)
    {
            node* newnode=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
            char* newstr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(token)+1);
            newstr[sizeof(token)]='\0';
            strcpy(newstr,token);
            newnode->left=left;
            newnode->right=right;
            newnode->token=newstr;
            return newnode;
    }
    void printtree(node* tree)
    {

            printf("%s\n",tree->token);
            if(tree->left)printtree(tree->left);
            if(tree->right)printtree(tree->right);
    }
    int yyerror()
    {
            printf("bla bla\n");
            return 0;
            }
```

---------------lex code:--------------------------------

```
minus "-"
colon ":"
semicolon ";"
space " "
parcent "%"
backslash "/"
charptr charptr
plus "+"
not "!"
notequal "!="
or "||"
and "&&"
multiply "*"
power "^"
dbland "&"
greater ">"
lesser "<"
return "return"
greaterequal {greater}{assign}
lesserequal {lesser}{assign}
singleQuotes \'
charERR {singleQuotes}+(({digit})+)*(({letter})+)*{singleQuotes}+
stringERR {doubleQuotes}{doubleQuotes}+|{doubleQuotes}
doubleQuotes \"
octalDigit [1-7]
decimal {digit}|{digitNoZero}{digit}+
digitNoZero[1-9]
octal "0"{octalDigit}("0")*{octalDigit}*
integer {binaryInt}|{hex}|{octal}|{decimal}
binaryInt ("0"|"1")+"b"
hexLetter A|B|C|D|E|F
hex 0(x|X){digit}+{hexLetter}*|0(x|X){digit}*{hexLetter}+
literBool true|false
letter [a-zA-Z]
letters {letter}+
digit [0-9]
low "_"
equal "=="
assign "="
devide "/"
lparen "("
rparen ")"
lparenc "{"
rparenc "}"
identifier {letter}+{digit}*{letter}+|{letter}
type boolean|string|char|integer|intptr|charptr|var
literChar {singleQuotes}{letter}{singleQuotes}
ltrlString {doubleQuotes}{letters}*{decimal}*{hex}*{octal}*{binaryInt}*{dbland}*$
pointer {colon}{space}{charptr}|"="{space}"&"{identifier}
comment {backslash}{parcent}{space}*({letters}*{space}*{identifier}*{space}*{dec$
pointerErr "&"{identifier}|{charptr}
statif "if"{space}*
ELSE "else"{space}*
comma ","
whileLoop "while"{space}*
main "main"
var "VAR"
%%
{lparen} return LPAREN;
{rparen} return RPAREN;
{colon} return COLON;
{semicolon} return SEMICOLON;
{var} return VAR;
{whileLoop} return WHILELOOP;
{ELSE} return ELSE;
{statif} return IF;
{pointerErr} return POINTERERR;
{comment} return COMMENT;
{pointer} return POINTER;
{literChar} return LITERCHAR;
{charERR} return CHARERROR;
{stringERR} return STRINGERROR;
{ltrlString} return LTRLSTRING;
{binaryInt} return BINARYINT;
{octal} return OCTAL;
{hex} return HEX;
{return} return RETURN;
{greaterequal} return GREATEREQUAL;
{lesserequal} return LESSEREQUAL;
{dbland} return DBLAND;
{greater} return GREATER;
{lesser} return LESSER;
{lparenc} return LPARENC;
{rparenc} return RPARENC;
{power} return POWER;
{multiply} return MULTIPLY;
{plus} return PLUS;
{or} return OR;
{and} return AND;
{comma} return COMMA;
{not} return NOT;
{main} return MAIN;
{notequal} return NOTEQUAL;
{minus} return MINUS;
{integer} return INTEGER;
{literBool} return BOOLEAN;
{identifier} return IDENTIFIER;
{equal} return EQUAL;
{assign} return ASSIGN;
{devide} return DEVIDE;
{type} return TYPE;
. return yytext[0];
```

Comment: Your `var` rule appears to be truncated.

Comment: this is a copy paste mistake.

Comment: var_declare: var {printtree($1);}
             var: VAR ident_list COLON TYPE    SEMICOLON{$$=mknode("var",$2,$4);}

Comment: Don't put corrections in comments; edit your question. Also, please try to reduce that to a [mcve]; the problem description should contain the precise input and corresponding output or error notification. Also, please compile with warnings enabled and fix anything which is causing a warning, before seeking assistance.

Comment: Your code is still not enough to compile. You should provide the lexer to start with.

Comment: Stefano Sanfilippo lex file exist.

Comment: But not in your incomplete question. And please format this illegible mess.

Comment: @user5757835 I know you have a lex file, but we need it, together with a test case, to be able to help you.

Comment: Stefano Sanfilippo  ok, i added lex file and re-edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do the final reduction `s: expression` and return, yacc needs to see the EOF at the end of the input.  If you are reading from a file, that EOF will come automatically, but there is no *end* to terminal input, so with input coming from a terminal, you'll need to give it an explicit EOF indication by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> on windows).

Comment: Ok tnx. One more question pls. How i tell the program to take the input from txt file.  (I'm working with putty)
My run commands are :
Lex ok.lex
Yacc ok.yacc
Cc -o ok.out y.tab.c -ll-Ly 
/.ok.out

Comment: There are a number of ways:  You can redirect stdin on the commandline with `<filename` when you run the program.  You can call `yyin = fopen("file", "r");` in `main` before calling `yyparse()`